# Using svg freestyle addon, the svg is completly blank

Tags: add-on, svg

I have tried on both windows and linux. I had seen a post saying it worked better in 2.79, but when I tried that, it crashed trying to load the file[image: This is what I am trying to make an svg (this is viewport render image)]

This is what I am trying to make an svg (this is viewport render image).
I am trying to make this for a board game, but I do not understand what would cause this to happen.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just recently used it in 2.93 and it definitely works as expected. Can you post screenshots of the freestyle and freestyle svg options in the render panel and the Viewlayer Properties?
You have to also activate the normal Freestyle Renderer for the add-on to work.